# MySQL InnoDB: autoincrement non-primary key

Tags: mysql, primary-key, innodb

Is it possible to auto-increment a *non-primary* key?

Table "book_comments"

```
book_id     medium_int
timestamp   medium_int
user_id     medium_int
vote_up     small_int
vote_down   small_int
comment     text
comment_id  medium_int

Primary key -> (book_id, timestamp, user_id)
```

There will be no other indexes on this table. However, I would like to make the `comment_id` column autoincrement so that I can easily create another table:

Table "book_comments_votes"

```
comment_id  (medium_int)
user_id     (medium_int)

Primary key -> (comment_id, user_id)
```

Users would be able to vote only once per book comment. This table enforces this rule by the primary key.

#### Question:

Is it possible to auto-increment a *non-primary* key - as in, auto-increment the `comment_id` column in table "book_comments"?

---

### Alternatives, Discussion.

I would like to do this for simplicity as explained above. The alternatives are not promising.

- Make the commnet_id PK and enforce integrity through a unique index on `book_id, timestamp, user_id`. In this case, I would create an additional index.
- Keep the PK and replace the comment_id in the `book_comments_votes` with the entire PK. This would more than triple the size of the table.

Suggestions? Thoughts?

Comment: Why can't you simply make `comment_id` the primary key? I don't understand why you would need the extra unique index. I'm probably just not fully understanding your problem.

Comment: `comment_id` as the PK would not be enough to enforce data integrity - specifically that there are no other duplicates user votes for a specific book. That's why a unique index is needed with a composite key.

Comment: So users can only vote once per book, not once per book comment as you stated in your question?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Yes you can. You just need to make that column be an index.

```
CREATE TABLE `test` (
  `testID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `string` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `testInc` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`testID`),
  KEY `testInc` (`testInc`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


insert into test(
  testID,
 string
)
values (
1,
    'Hello'
);


insert into test( 
testID,
 string
)
values (
2,
    'world'
);
```

Will insert rows with auto-incrementing values for 'testInc'. However this is a really dumb thing to do.

You already said the right way to do it:

"Make the comment_id PK and enforce integrity through a unique index on book_id, timestamp, user_id."

That's exactly the way that you should be doing it. Not only does it provide you with a proper primary key key for the table which you will need for future queries, it also satisfies [the principle of least astonishment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment).

Comment: "this is a really dumb thing to do".  That's strong.  Every quirk has its use case.  I have large text-based keys which I'd rather not propagate throughout my design.  A surrogate key fits the bill.

Comment: A surrogate key is what I suggested they use, instead of their original silly idea.

Comment: Thank you so much you are a big help :))

Comment: It's not just strong, it's a wrong comment.  While he's right that having a proper key is a good thing. It doesn't mean that a complex key made of various columns is the best solution at all.  a primary integer id is very portable, a complex key not necessarily.

Comment: even if it does allow auto_increment on any index, I'd at the very least make it a unique index.  a non-unique index that auto increments seems like a recipe for disaster

Answer (score 2):

You've existing table. If you already gave a primary key to `comment_id` and the only purpose is to set auto_increment. You can drop the primary key to that column. MySQL allows a column with any key property can access auto_increment. So better try an index or `unique key` to `comment_id` like below.

1.Remove Primary Key

```
ALTER TABLE `book_comments` MODIFY `comment_id` INT(5) NOT NULL;

ALTER TABLE `book_comments` DROP PRIMARY KEY ;
```

2. Add `AUTO_INCREMENT` with `UNIQUE_KEY` property.

`ALTER TABLE 'brand_keywords' CHANGE COLUMN 'comment_id' 'comment_id' INT(5) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT UNIQUE;`

Answer (score 0):

As of MySQL 5.5, it seems to be possible without <strike>an index or</strike> primary key an INT field to be provided with autoincrement.

Comment: Can you ? Post your code please. I tried in 5.5.23 and 5.6.12:

    > create table test ( user varchar(20)  not null, id int auto_increment,  primary key(user));  
    ERROR 1075 (42000): Incorrect table definition; there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key

Comment: Sorry u have to add an Index, my fault.

create table test 
( user varchar(20) not null, 
id int auto_increment, 
index (id), 
primary key (user))

Comment: Can you mention the reference?