# #1075 MySQL Error

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-error-1075

So i am just a beginner in all this php stuff. I know just the basics, and when i setting up the settings for my new table, I met the problem #1075. Before, i created one, almost similar to this one, and i don't see the differenc. Can you say me where is the problem and explain what is happening?

```
CREATE TABLE `try`.`testing` ( `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT , `date` DATE NOT NULL , `text_1` TEXT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL , `text_2` TEXT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL ) ENGINE = MyISAM;
```

here is the code of my SQL Preview. I use phpMyAdmin, obviously.
Please, help me.
Thank, you)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
CREATE TABLE `testing` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
  `date` DATE NOT NULL, 
  `text_1` TEXT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL, 
  `text_2` TEXT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE = MYISAM ;
```

Comment: Thank, you! Works well, but can you explain what you did? What was the problem.

Comment: for AUTO_INCREMENT column we mush have key, so I have set it as primary key

Answer (score 1):

You have to declare your `AUTO_INCREMENT` field as a `primary key` or a `key`. So you have to add `PRIMARY KEY (id)` or `KEY (id)` to your `CREATE TABLE` statement:

```
CREATE TABLE `try`.`testing` ( 
`id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
`date` DATE NOT NULL , 
`text_1` TEXT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL , 
`text_2` TEXT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`) -- as primary key
KEY (`id`) -- or as key
) ENGINE = MyISAM;
```

Please also check:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/8114994/3647441

https://stackoverflow.com/a/14087703/3647441

Answer (score 0):

For an `autoincrement` field you should have some sort of index associated with it. eg: `primary key` which is missing

Answer (score 0):

Try This.

```
CREATE TABLE `try`.`testing` ( 
`id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
`date` DATE NOT NULL , 
`text_1` TEXT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL , 
`text_2` TEXT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL,
KEY (`id`) 
) ENGINE = MyISAM;
```

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/example-auto-increment.html

Comment: The already fixed this problem, but thank you)
What means this **-- or as key**

Comment: means you can use primary key or any key in the id. the auto_increment increment by key