# Mysql single query with subquery or two separate queries

Tags: php, mysql

I've table with following structure :

```
id | storeid | code
```

Where `id` is primary key

I want to insert data in this table with incremental order like this :

```
id | storeid | code
1  |       2 | 1 
2  |       2 | 2 
3  |       2 | 3 
4  |       2 | 4
```

I've two solution to do this task.

1) Fire a query to get last record (`code`) from table and increment value of `code` with `1` using PHP and after that second query to insert that incremented value in database.

2) This single query :  `"INSERT INTO qrcodesforstore (storeid,code) VALUES (2,IFNULL((SELECT t.code+1 FROM (select code from qrcodesforstore order by id desc limit 1) t),1))"`

I just want suggestion which approach is best and why for performance.
I'm currently using second method but confuse about performance as I'm using three level sub query.

Comment: I think you can set `AUTO_INCREMENT` to a column when creating a table. Also you need to make an index for this column

Comment: `Id` is already set to `AUTO_INCREMENT` . I'm talking about field `code`.

Comment: I am talking about `code` field as well

Comment: As i already said i've `id` field and i dont want two `AUTO_INCREMENT` field in my db.

Comment: I would use a single query, as to queries means 2 trips to the database which is a large over head (and the chance of another insert happening at that moment so you get duplicates). But I wouldn't use the ordered sub query you are using. Another option would be a trigger to add the value on insert.

Comment: @Kickstart Completely agree with this : `The chance of another insert happening at that moment so you get duplicates`. I never thought about that. And can you please explain me how this can be achieve with trigger in your answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrapping it up in a trigger:-

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS bi_qrcodesforstore$$
CREATE TRIGGER bi_qrcodesforstore BEFORE INSERT ON qrcodesforstore
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    DECLARE max_code    INT;
    SELECT MAX(code) INTO max_code FROM qrcodesforstore;
    IF max_code IS NULL THEN
        SET max_code := 1;
    ELSE
        SET max_code := max_code + 1;
    END IF
    SET NEW.code := max_code;
END
```

Comment: But how this trigger will fire. For that i need to insert some data in database with query.

Comment: Yes, if you insert a row the trigger is automatically fired off and will give the next value of code for the insert

Comment: So on first insert i add blank data into `code` field and this trigger will update `code` field with `max+1`. That's what you are saying?

Comment: You do not even need to add anything in the code field on the insert statement (and if you did it would be ignored). Just do _INSERT INTO qrcodesforstore (id, storeid) VALUES(NULL, 5535)_

Answer (score 1):

You simply can use INSERT with SELECT and MAX():

```
INSERT INTO qrcodesforstore 
(storeid, code) 
(SELECT 2, IFNULL((MAX(code)+1),1) FROM qrcodesforstore)
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/de1538/4)

Answer (score 0):

[image]you declare the field as primary key and unique and auto increment key they automatically increment the values

Comment: I don't want two `AUTO_INCREMENT` field in my db. Thanks

Comment: simply after inserting of last data get last_insert id to update that record.

Comment: Thanks again for comment. Please read my question carefully what i want to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `code` column as `AUTO_INCREMENT`, you don't need to set it as primary key, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14087703/4922156).

Anyway, the second solution would be better, only one query is better than two.

Comment: I know one query is better than two. That's why I'm using it. But what about sub queries. Is it OK?