# how to resolve requests that arrive at the same time

Tags: php, mysql

I have a problem when submitting a form, when the data is sent to create in the database, if 2 requests arrive at the same time 2 records are created with the same code, there is a column (not the primary key, not auto-incrementing) formed by characters and numbers and each time a record is created the id is increased.

I am using php and mysql,it is very unlikely that it will happen but it has happened, how could I avoid this? Thank you

Comment: If you want unicity in your DB, just create a unique index on this field and handle unicity constraint errors (https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-unique-constraint/) in your code.

Comment: *"each time a record is created the id is increased"* - Then why not use an auto-incrementing field?  It sounds like it [doesn't need to be the primary key](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14087703/328193).

Comment: It is a column similar to a primary key since it must be unique but it is made up of characters and numbers, the problem is that if I send 2 forms with different information from different places but at the same time the 2 records with different information are created but they remain with the same code.

Comment: Either you need to fix how the key is generated or use unique indexes as suggested and handle duplicate key errors.

Comment: You need a better **sequence generator**. You need one that avoids *race conditions*.

Comment: A query is made to obtain the last number created, it is increased by 1 and then it is concatenated with a text, this in a function that returns this code

Comment: That's a classic example of a race condition: Fetch, increment and set. You can't do that. You need an *atomic statement*. There are many examples of sequence generators that do this correctly and reliably. Find one and adapt to your needs.

Comment: Thank you very much everyone for the help